# VBA Access No Current Record Error

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I cant seem to figure out this error, and all I want is to be able continue to the next item I am trying to include in the email.

I am using queries to send emails via Access.

```
Dim MyDb As DAO.Database
Dim rsEmail As DAO.Recordset
Dim InfoQuery As DAO.Recordset
Dim secondQuery As DAO.Recordset


Dim sToName As String
Dim sSubject As String
Dim sMessageBody As String
Dim test As String
Dim test2 As String

Set MyDb = CurrentDb()
Set rsEmail = MyDb.OpenRecordset("firstEmailCAD", dbOpenSnapshot)
Set InfoQuery = MyDb.OpenRecordset("InformationTableQueryEmail", dbOpenSnapshot)
Set secondQuery = MyDb.OpenRecordset("secondEmailCAD", dbOpenSnapshot)

test = rsEmail.Fields(2)
test2 = ""

With rsEmail

        If IsNull(test) Then
           test2 = test2 & "0"
        End If

        InfoQuery.MoveFirst
        Do Until rsEmail.EOF
            If IsNull(InfoQuery.Fields(0)) = False Then
                sToName = InfoQuery.Fields(0)
                sSubject = "Earnings for: " & InfoQuery.Fields(1)
                sMessageBody = "Email Body Text " & vbCrLf & _
                    "Field A: " & .Fields(1) & vbCrLf & _
                    **"Field B: " & test2 & vbCrLf & _**
                    "Field C: " & secondQuery.Fields(2)

                DoCmd.SendObject acSendNoObject, , , _
                    sToName, , , sSubject, sMessageBody, False, False
            End If
            .MoveNext
        Loop
End With

Set MyDb = Nothing
Set rsEmail = Nothing
Set InfoQuery = Nothing
Set secondQuery = Nothing
```

So the rsEmail query doesn't have a record at the moment, it depends on the day whether it will have a record or not, but what I want to do is be able to assign 0 to a specific column on that query.

test = rsEmail.Fields(2) --> this gives an error as No current record, considering I am only using it in an if statement, so I can put 0 when I create the message

I am new to VBA Access, any help will be appreciated :)

Thank you,

Comment: If no records, then you can't reference a field in the dataset. Use "If  rsEmail.Eof then Test = 0 else test = RSEmail.Fields(2)"

Comment: Also note that strings cannot be null, they can be zero-length. This: `test2 = ""` is not necessary, this: `If IsNull(test) Then
           test2 = test2 & "0"
        End If` will never be triggered. If you want a type that can be null, you can use the variant type, but it will cost you memory.

Answer (score 3):

As Wayne puts it you should check if you have records at all BEFORE the command

```
InfoQuery.MoveFirst
```

In general it would be better to check both .BOF and .EOF

So it would be something like this:

```
If Not (InfoQuery.EOF And InfoQuery.BOF) Then
  InfoQuery.MoveFirst
  .....
Else
  'manage the lack of records condition here
  ....
End If
```

If a recordset has no records both BOF and EOF are set to true